# Couldn't list the stuffs from the models to HTML page in Django

Tags: python, django

Couldn't connect the list view to HTML file in Django.

****models.py****

```
class AccountList(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
paltform=models.CharField(max_length=200)
username=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
comments=models.TextField()
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("accdetail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

****views.py****

```
class Account_list(ListView):
model=AccountList
def get_queryset(self):
    return AccountList.objects.all()
```

****AccountList_list.html****

```
{% extends 'PasswordSafe/base.html' %}
{% block content  %}
<div class="centerstage">
{% for acc in acc_list %}
<h1><a href="{% url 'accdetail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ acc.name }}</a></h1>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns=[url(r'^$',views.HomePageView.as_view(),name="hmpage"),
url(r'^accountlist/',views.Account_list.as_view(),name="acc_list"),
url(r'^newsafe/',views.NewSafe.as_view(),name="new_safe"),
url(r'^accdetail/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.AccDetail.as_view(),name="accdetail"),
url(r'^about/',views.AboutPage.as_view(),name="about")]
```

I Don't Know where did i go wrong.

Comment: What is this acc_list??? Where is it defined????{% for acc in acc_list %}

Comment: url(r'^accountlist/',views.Account_list.as_view(),name="acc_list")

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works for you.

```
class Account_list(ListView):
    model = AccountList
    template_name = 'AccountList_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        acc_list = AccountList.objects.all()
        context = super(Account_list,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['acc_list'] = acc_list
        return context
```

Comment: i get a blank page...but i need all the stuffs from models to be listed in the html page

Comment: Check this line.<h1><a href="{% url 'acc_list' pk=post.pk %}">{{ acc.name }}</a></h1> channging accdetail to acc_list

Comment: no,that is a href tag. it refers to another url...when i click on the acc.name it redirects me to the accdetail